# Помогите написать простейший слайдер на js

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Я хочу разобраться как сделать слайдер.Посмотрел море видосов и не нашел ни одного просто нормального,все делают какие то анимации или пишут миллион строк кода.Может кто то написать код самого просто слайдера или дать ссылку на него?чтобы он по клику на кнопку менял стиль текущего слайда на display none, а следующего dislpay block.ну или через remove().При этом все слайды находятся или в html или в массиве в js.Вот что у меня получилось по видосам но тут видно что много лишнего + назад слайды не переключаются.Я уверен что его можно сделать намного проще.Заранее спасибо.
Сладер надо сделать на чистом js.

```
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-single');

console.log(slides)
let slider = [];

for (let i = 0; i < slides.length;i++){
    slider[i] = slides[i].src;
    slides[i].remove();
}
console.log(slider);

let step = 0;
let offset = 0;

function draw(){
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = slider[step];
    img.classList.add('slide-single');
    document.querySelector('#slide').appendChild(img);
    if (step +1 == slider.lenght){
        step = 0;
    }
    else{
        step++;
    }
    offset = 0;
    };


function next(){
    let nextSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-single');
    let offset2 = 0;
    for (let i = 0 ; i< nextSlide.lenght;i++){
        if(nextSlide.lenght = -1){
            nextSlide = 0
        }else(nextSlide++)
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            nextSlide[0].remove();
            draw();
        },500);
};

function previous(){
    let previousSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-single');
    let offset2 = 0;
    for (let i = 0 ; i< previousSlide.lenght;i--){
        offset2--;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            previousSlide[0].remove();
        },500);
};

next();
draw();

let nextButton = document.querySelector('.nextButton');
let previousButton = document.querySelector('.previousButton');

previousButton.onclick = function(event) {
    previous();
  };

nextButton.onclick = function(event) {
    next();
  };
```

Я искал вот это.Очень легко и просто

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-collection ,img');
let current = 0;

console.log(images)

function slider(){
    for (let i = 0;i<images.length;i++){
        images[i].classList.add('opacity0');
    }
    images[current].classList.remove('opacity0');

}
slider();
document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function(){
    if (current -1 == -1){
        current  = images.length -1  ;
    }else{
        current--;
    }
    slider();
}

document.querySelector('.next').onclick = function(){
    if (current -1 == images.length){
        current  = 0;
    }else{
        current++;
    }
    slider();
}
```

Comment: Начните делать слайдер. Если появятся конкретные вопрос - спрашивайте! В таком виде на ваш вопрос скорее всего не ответят - он слишком общий.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а я хочу написать, не писал ещё сам слайдер :D

Comment: [можно тут посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064830/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-active/1064838#1064838)

Comment: [а можно и тут](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js+%2B+css&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruUA842UA842&oq=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BD%D0%B0+js+%2B+css&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8687j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 15):

Достаточно минималистично?

---

Весь фокус в формуле вычисления следующего слайда:

`index = (index + dir + imgs.length) % imgs.length`

прибавляем к текущему индексу направление (+1 или -1) и находим остаток от деления на кол-во картинок, длина прибавляется для обработки отрицательных значений (переброс в положительную область и нахождение остатка от деления там)

```js
let imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')]

function go(dir) {
  let index = imgs.indexOf(document.querySelector('.visible'));
  imgs[index].classList.remove('visible');
  imgs[(index + dir + imgs.length) % imgs.length].classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=go(-1)><</button>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/300/150" class='visible'>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/300/150">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/300/150">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/14/300/150">
<button onclick=go(1)>></button>
```

---

Немного более симпатичный вариант

```js
document.querySelectorAll('slider').forEach(slider => {
  let imgs = [...slider.querySelectorAll('img')];
  imgs[0].classList.add('visible');
  slider.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let r = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
    let dir = Math.sign(e.x-r.x-r.width/2);
    let index = imgs.indexOf(document.querySelector('.visible'));
    imgs[index].classList.remove('visible');
    imgs[(index + dir + imgs.length) % imgs.length].classList.add('visible');  
  })
});
```

```css
slider img {
  display: none;
}

slider .visible {
  display: unset;
}

slider {
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

slider::after {
   margin-left: -300px;
   content:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='5' width='300' height='150'><path d='m 30 55 l -20 20 l 20 20' /><path d='m 270 55 l 20 20 l -20 20' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
<slider>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/14/300/150">
</slider>
```

---

B И пусть будет еще один представитель этого семейства минималистичных слайдеров:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('slider').forEach(s => {
  const imgs = [...s.querySelectorAll('img')];
  const update = n => s.style.backgroundPosition = 
      imgs.map((_, i) => `${s.clientWidth*(i-n)}px 0px`).join(',');  
  s.style.backgroundImage =  imgs.map(img => `url(${img.src})`).join(',');
  imgs.forEach((img, n) => img.onclick = () => update(n));
  update(0);
});
```

```css
slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

slider img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 124px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<slider>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/13/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/14/300/150">
</slider>

<slider>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/300/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/24/300/150">
</slider>
```

Comment: можно еще минималистичнее ?

Comment: зачетный слайдер ) сразу в продакшен )

Comment: это просто супер. короче только подключить плагин )

Comment: @АлексейОбухов вопрос был как сделать :)

Comment: Какие то сложные формулы, я думал будет что то на подобии цикла который при клике делает первый невидимый слайд а второй видимый, а тут формулы с вычислениями

Comment: @drotsyk можете сделать и так, но будет 2 if :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а есть какие то гайды по написанию таких формул вычитания? или это личный опыт?просто я б до такого никогда не додумался,да и вообще я % и очень редко использую

Answer (score 3):

Переменная num - это счётчик, показывает какой активный сейчас слайд. Я на всякий случай задаю активному слайду класс `.active`, вдруг им кто-то будет пользоваться

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let slider__items = slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__item');
let buttons = slider.querySelectorAll('.btn__slider');
let button__prev = buttons[0];
let button__next = buttons[1];
let maxItems = slider__items.length;

let num = 0;

function transformNum(znak) {
  let backElem, frontElem;
  if (znak === 'minus') {
    backElem = slider__items[num + 1];
    frontElem = slider__items[num];
    backElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0) scale(0)`;
    frontElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0) scale(1)`;
  } else if (znak === 'plus') {
    backElem = slider__items[num - 1];
    frontElem = slider__items[num];
    backElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0) scale(0)`;
    frontElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0) scale(1)`;
  }
}

function addActive(znak) {
  let elem;
  if (znak === 'minus') {
    if (num - 1 === -1) {
      return;
    }
    num--;
    transformNum(znak);
    elem = slider__items[num + 1];
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (znak === 'plus') {
    if (num + 1 === maxItems) {
      return;
    }
    num++;
    transformNum(znak);
    elem = slider__items[num - 1];
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  }
  elem = slider__items[num];
  elem.classList.add('active');
}

button__prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addActive('minus');
});

button__next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addActive('plus');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

main.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider__items {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider__item {
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.slider__item img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.btn__slider {
  min-width: 9%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.btn__slider .icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  transform: translate(75%, 50%) rotate(135deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .2s linear, width .5s linear, height .5s linear;
}

.btn__slider__next .icon {
  transform: translate(25%, 50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.btn__slider:hover .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn__slider:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .btn__slider .icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .btn__slider {
    min-width: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="content">

  <div class="slider">

    <a class="btn__slider btn__slider__prev">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </a>

    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/2000">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/1200">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/700">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .slider__items -->

    <a class="btn__slider btn__slider__next">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <!-- .slider -->

</main>
```

А вот вариант без `transform: scale()`

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let slider__items = slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__item');
let buttons = slider.querySelectorAll('.btn__slider');
let button__prev = buttons[0];
let button__next = buttons[1];
let maxItems = slider__items.length;

let num = 0;

function transformNum(znak) {
  let backElem, frontElem;
  if (znak === 'minus') {
    backElem = slider__items[num + 1];
    frontElem = slider__items[num];
    backElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0)`;
    frontElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0)`;
  } else if (znak === 'plus') {
    backElem = slider__items[num - 1];
    frontElem = slider__items[num];
    backElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0)`;
    frontElem.style.transform = `translateZ(0px) translate(${-1 * num * 100}%, 0)`;
  }
}

function addActive(znak) {
  let elem;
  if (znak === 'minus') {
    if (num - 1 === -1) {
      return;
    }
    num--;
    transformNum(znak);
    elem = slider__items[num + 1];
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (znak === 'plus') {
    if (num + 1 === maxItems) {
      return;
    }
    num++;
    transformNum(znak);
    elem = slider__items[num - 1];
    elem.classList.remove('active');
  }
  elem = slider__items[num];
  elem.classList.add('active');
}

button__prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addActive('minus');
});

button__next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addActive('plus');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

main.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider__items {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider__item {
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.slider__item img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.btn__slider {
  min-width: 9%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.btn__slider .icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  border-right: 4px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  transform: translate(75%, 50%) rotate(135deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .2s linear, width .5s linear, height .5s linear;
}

.btn__slider__next .icon {
  transform: translate(25%, 50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.btn__slider:hover .icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn__slider:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .btn__slider .icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .btn__slider {
    min-width: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="content">

  <div class="slider">

    <a class="btn__slider btn__slider__prev">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </a>

    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/2000">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/1200">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/700">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .slider__items -->

    <a class="btn__slider btn__slider__next">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <!-- .slider -->

</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Простой слайдер:

```js
 'use strict';
    var multiItemSlider = (function () {
      return function (selector, config) {
        var
          _mainElement = document.querySelector(selector), // основный элемент блока
          _sliderWrapper = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__wrapper'), // обертка для .slider-item
          _sliderItems = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), // элементы (.slider-item)
          _sliderControls = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), // элементы управления
          _sliderControlLeft = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_left'), // кнопка "LEFT"
          _sliderControlRight = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_right'), // кнопка "RIGHT"
          _wrapperWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderWrapper).width), // ширина обёртки
          _itemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderItems[0]).width), // ширина одного элемента    
          _positionLeftItem = 0, // позиция левого активного элемента
          _transform = 0, // значение транфсофрмации .slider_wrapper
          _step = _itemWidth / _wrapperWidth * 100, // величина шага (для трансформации)
          _items = []; // массив элементов
        // наполнение массива _items
        _sliderItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
          _items.push({ item: item, position: index, transform: 0 });
        });

        var position = {
          getMin: 0,
          getMax: _items.length - 1,
        }

        var _transformItem = function (direction) {
          if (direction === 'right') {
            if ((_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth - 1) >= position.getMax) {
              return;
            }
            if (!_sliderControlLeft.classList.contains('slider__control_show')) {
              _sliderControlLeft.classList.add('slider__control_show');
            }
            if (_sliderControlRight.classList.contains('slider__control_show') && (_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth) >= position.getMax) {
              _sliderControlRight.classList.remove('slider__control_show');
            }
            _positionLeftItem++;
            _transform -= _step;
          }
          if (direction === 'left') {
            if (_positionLeftItem <= position.getMin) {
              return;
            }
            if (!_sliderControlRight.classList.contains('slider__control_show')) {
              _sliderControlRight.classList.add('slider__control_show');
            }
            if (_sliderControlLeft.classList.contains('slider__control_show') && _positionLeftItem - 1 <= position.getMin) {
              _sliderControlLeft.classList.remove('slider__control_show');
            }
            _positionLeftItem--;
            _transform += _step;
          }
          _sliderWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transform + '%)';
        }

        // обработчик события click для кнопок "назад" и "вперед"
        var _controlClick = function (e) {
          if (e.target.classList.contains('slider__control')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var direction = e.target.classList.contains('slider__control_right') ? 'right' : 'left';
            _transformItem(direction);
          }
        };

        var _setUpListeners = function () {
          // добавление к кнопкам "назад" и "вперед" обрботчика _controlClick для событя click
          _sliderControls.forEach(function (item) {
            item.addEventListener('click', _controlClick);
          });
        }

        // инициализация
        _setUpListeners();

        return {
          right: function () { // метод right
            _transformItem('right');
          },
          left: function () { // метод left
            _transformItem('left');
          }
        }

      }
    }());

    var slider = multiItemSlider('.slider')
```

```css
/*!
     * chiefSlider (https://itchief.ru/lessons/php/feedback-form-for-website)
     * Copyright 2018 Alexander Maltsev
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/itchief/feedback-form/blob/master/LICENSE)
     */

    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      color: #fff;
      height: 3000px;
    }

    .slider {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slider__wrapper {
      display: flex;
      transition: transform 0.6s ease;
    }

    .slider__item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .slider__control {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      display: none;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 40px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      opacity: 0.5;
      height: 50px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

    .slider__control_show {
      display: flex;
    }

    .slider__control:hover,
    .slider__control:focus {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: 0;
      opacity: .9;
    }

    .slider__control_left {
      left: 0;
    }

    .slider__control_right {
      right: 0;
    }

    .slider__control::before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: transparent no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .slider__control_left::before {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }

    .slider__control_right::before {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }

    .slider__item>div {
      line-height: 250px;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>JavaScript - Как сделать слайдер для сайта</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: orange;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: green;">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: violet;">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: coral;">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Еще вариант...с `bootstrap 4`

```js
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container mt-3" style="height:300px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <div class="h2 text-center">Слайдер на bootstrap 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide h-100" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://maxtextures.ru/assets/images/resources/206/420593-858994881bea1e525507e457fc0018ca.jpg" height="300px" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/11/66/cc11665c0f6565ab973907a73fa7d8b5.jpg" height="300px" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://hdoboi.kiev.ua/images/30.Aug.2019-vesennij-pejzazh.jpg" height="300px" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проще не бывает :D

Comment: В свое время именно по таким простым гайдам и не хотел лезть в js спагетти, но шутку оценил, плюс влепил